# How to close CefSharp Session winforms vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, cefsharp

I've been struggling to close the current session when the form is closed and re opened

https://www.facebook.com

What I expect to happen:

- Open form
- log in in: https://www.facebook.com
- close form
- reopen form
- session is closed and I can log in with different credentials

What actually happens:

- Open form
- log in in: https://www.facebook.com
- close form
- reopen form
- session is still open with previous credentials

```
Imports CefSharp.WinForms
Imports CefSharp

Public Class MasOrdenAPP


    Private Sub MasOrdenAPP_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.FormBorderStyle = 0
    End Sub

    Private WithEvents browser As ChromiumWebBrowser

    Public Sub New()


        CefSharp.Cef.Shutdown()

        InitializeComponent()

        Dim settings As New CefSettings()

        CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings)

        CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager.DeleteCookies("", "")

        browser = New ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.facebook.com/") With {.Dock = DockStyle.Fill}
        browser.BrowserSettings.ApplicationCache = CefState.Disabled
      
        Panel1.Controls.Add(browser)

    End Sub

    Private Sub bCerrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bCerrar.Click
        CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager.DeleteCookies("", "")
      
        Me.Close()
        Home.Activate()
    End Sub

    Private Sub MasOrdenAPP_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
        'CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager.DeleteCookies("", "")
    End Sub

End Class
```

I tried `CefSharp.Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager.DeleteCookies("", "")`
but only works with Facebook and reddit, not with the site I actually need it to work.

I tried using `browser.dispose()` but it disables the browser and when I try to reopen the form it doesn't work anymore

I tried:

```
settings.CachePath = ""
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add ("disable-application-cache", "1")
settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("disable-session-storage", "1")
```

It doesn't seem to do anything at all.

If this isn't possible in CEF, is there any way to reset or dispose the CEF browser every time the form is closed so every time the form opens it ask you for your credentials like the first time?

Comment: You can use a RequestContext to isolate your browser instances. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation

Comment: Hi @amaitland thanks for you response, I'm really new to cefsharp I've been working with it for a couple days, can you elaborate a bit more on what is the idea of using a RequestContext?, i read the link you posted and I'm trying to understand how it works or what it does but I'm a bit lost.

Comment: You can create a new ChromiumWebBrowser instance with a new RequestContext and it will have a different cache.

Comment: Remove the ChromiumWebBrowser instance from it's parent control, then create a new ChromiumWebBrowser instance with a new RequestContext and you'll have a new in memory cache.